# Vb script for Speech to text (speech recognition)?

Tags: vbscript

this is Text to speech script, its very easy, just put this in notepad and save as anyname.vbs

> CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak"Hello"

open the file, the computer will say Hello
like from this tutorial http://www.bustatech.com/get-the-gender-of-your-pc/

but how to do the opposite (Speech to text script or speech recognition), please help how is the script?

Comment: What you want is not supported.

Comment: @Ansgar : answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027773/use-of-sapi-speech-recognition-in-a-vbs-script ... 7 years later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for speech recognition, but im not sure if it works in Vbscript, I know it works in google chrome --- or in html connected to google crhome. Visit this site-
http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/

try microsoft speech recognition.

Comment: Here is a sample script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027773/use-of-sapi-speech-recognition-in-a-vbs-script . I hope it still helps ;-)