# Use of SAPI Speech Recognition in a VBS Script?

Tags: vbscript, speech-recognition, sapi

I found this one-line example that allows to use the Windows SAPI Text-to-Speech feature in VBScript:

```
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak("This is a test")
```

I wonder if the SAPI Speech Recognition could be used in a VBScript program in the same easy way. When I seek for such information the tons of SAPI information that appear are related to C++, like the [Microsoft SAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) site, or to Text-to-Speech in VBS. I tried to find documentation about the SAPI COM object Speech Recognition part that could be used in a VBScript, but found none.

Do you know if such a documentation exists? TIA

**EDIT**: *Additional request added after the first answer was recevied*

Although the first answer below provide a link to the SAPI COM object documentation, I want to attract your attention to a point in my question: "I wonder if the SAPI Speech Recognition could be used in a VBScript program **IN THE SAME EASY WAY**". The SAPI documentation is *huge*! I read several pages of it and I am completely lost... My goal is to recognize just a few single words, say 8 or 10, and show a different message in the screen each time that one of they was recognized; that is it! (The program should be a console application started via `cscript`). Is there a *simple* example of VBS code that achieve such thing? If the required code to program this solution needs to have several pages, then it is not the answer I am looking for...

Comment: Did you take a look at the [C&C recognition code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I copy-pasted the example at that link in test.vbs file, executed it via `cscript //nologo test.vbs` and got this (equivalent) error: "test.vbs(1, 19) Microsoft VBScript compiler error: End of instruction expected". I use Windows 8.1 Spanish version and cscript Windows Script Host version 5.8

Comment: I think you need to make some adjustments to the code, since it's VB, not VBScript. The latter doesn't support things like `On Error Goto MARK`, and you'd have to replace object creation of the form `Set RC = New SpSharedRecoContext` with `CreateObject()` and the full component name: `Set RC = CreateObject("SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext")`.

Comment: Did you find yourself anything new since then?

Comment: @Wolf: No, sorry. I tried to write a working example using all the compiled data, but the program did not worked _in VBS_, that is, in a program compiled by `cscript.exe`. There are a series of changes intended to adjust the program to the VBS environment, but they never worked. It is much simpler to write a C++ program for this...

Comment: @Aacini I see, thanks for the short report.

Comment: @Wolf, Aacini: I just posted an answer with a working vbscript example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of **vbscript** *listening* a wav file:

```
scriptRunning = true

Sub rc_Recognition(StreamNumber, StreamPosition, RecognitionType, Result)
  Wscript.Echo "Reco: ", Result.PhraseInfo.GetText, ".", RecognitionType
End Sub

Sub rc_StartStream(StreamNumber, StreamPosition)
  Wscript.Echo "Start: ", StreamNumber, StreamPosition
End Sub

Sub rc_EndStream(StreamNumber, StreamPosition, StreamReleased)
  Wscript.Echo "End: ", StreamNumber, StreamPosition, StreamReleased
  scriptRunning = false
End Sub


outwav = "C:\SOFT\projects\af2t\t.wav"
Const SAFT22kHz16BitMono = 22
Const SSFMOpenForRead = 0

set sapiFStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
sapiFStream.Format.Type = SAFT16kHz16BitMono
sapiFStream.Open outwav, SSFMOpenForRead


MsgBox "A SpeechLib::ISpRecoContext object will be created"

Const SGDSActive = 1

Set rct = WScript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpInProcRecoContext", "rc_")
Set rgnz = rct.Recognizer
Set rgnz.AudioInputStream = sapiFStream
Set rcGrammar = rct.CreateGrammar
'rcGrammar.DictationLoad
rcGrammar.DictationSetState SGDSActive
i = 0
while scriptRunning and i < 100
  WScript.Sleep(50)
  i = i + 1
wend

MsgBox "A SpeechLib::ISpRecoContext object has been created"
```

The magical part of the code is this line (the "rc_" *prefix* param allows events to be caught by the subs):

```
Set rct = WScript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpInProcRecoContext", "rc_")
```

The recorded text in the t.wav file I used for testing has been generated with SAPI.SpVoice::Speak and MS-David voice ;-)

I spent 10 days figuring out *how to* write this script. Microsoft is removing documentation about automation, COM, old style scripts, etc. A shame.

So, this works in dictation mode reading a wav file. But I couldn't correct it to make it work in live dictation mode (i.e. using the microphone as direct input). Any help appreciated for this. Thanks.

**EDIT:** direct/live dictation mode solved. If interested I share the vbscript code.

**EDIT2:** text sample spoken in the wav: `Hello world. This is a talk about gear tooth profile using a circle involute.`
Console output from the vbscript

```
C:\SOFT\projects\af2t>cscript r.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

Start:  1 0
Reco:  Hello world . 0
Reco:  this is a talk about gear to the profile using a circle invalid . 0
End:  1 195040 -1

C:\SOFT\projects\af2t>
```

Comment: Great to read it works for you. If you as well add the text-to-wav part, there is a big chance to collect positive replies for this answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Wolf : You mean text-to-speech saved in wav file ? If you share the link with the question I'd be glad to answer. The OP Aacini's question is about speech-to-text, so I just answered to that ;-)

Comment: I see. BTW (finding or asking the question will take some time): did you ever encounter problems with unicode in the text source? I failed with this when trying to output Polish numbers (Polish language was installed successfully, but VB seemed to have problems with utf-8 input), I really have little experience with VB Script...

Comment: @Wolf : here is an answered *text-to-speech saved to wav file* question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498004/how-to-save-sapi-text-to-speech-to-an-audio-file-in-vbscript .
I'm used to english and latin languages, I didn't encountered encoding issues (yet...).

Comment: Thanks :-) Perhaps I should have added that I was not interested in getting told the reverse part of above (which I already tried since it's a lot easier), but in the self-containment of this example. (IOW, `Debug.Assert(text = codec(text))`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Look at the [SAPI Automation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); it will tell you all about the late-bound COM interfaces and objects available to VBScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please, see the edit in my question above. If I don't receive an answer with additional information in a reasonable lapse, I will select this answer...

Comment: You could take http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125181(v=vs.85).aspx as a starting point. Still contains stuff you don´t want to know, but...compact enough to create you own experiments.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers comment is a pretty good starting point.  SR is simply more difficult than TTS; you have to define what you're listening for, and then do something with the results.